# Internal forward action in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter

In Zend Framework, we can easily forward to an action in another controller using the **_forward**().

How to simulate this in CI? CI only have **redirect** but this is not I want, I don't want user to see the URL has changed in their browser.

Any idea to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know for a fact that you can forward to another action inside the same controller without changing the url., with

```
$this->action();
```

Other than that, I do not see a built in way to access other controllers

This concept actually seems to break a more strict view of the MVC model, and this functionality you are trying to implement might be better suited for a library.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like HMVC (Hierarchical MHV) - i.e. controllers being able to load controllers without having to go through the HTTP interface again.  You can install a package called Modular Extensions (by wiredesignz).  Get the very latest from bitbucket, https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/overview.

Note that support for codeigniter V1.7 has been recently discontinued, so you'll need to user CI V2.0