# code igniter check authenticted user at contructer of the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

is it possible to check user authentication at constructor function of code igniter controller?

user controller

```
class user extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this -> load -> model('user_model');
    if (!$this -> user_model -> logged_in()) {
        $this -> load -> view('user/login');

    } else {
        return TRUE;

    }
   }

}
```

while i running this i got login view top of my dashboard after login. before login i get two login view. i tried this for minimize to repeatedly check is user loggedin  or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show login page with out change the url, You should do forward method. But CI have not method for forward.

check following answers. 
[Internal forward action in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841951/internal-forward-action-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score -1):

Just do a simple session check like where you check the session validity of the user if set or not:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_user')){
    redirect('controller/function', 'refresh');
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function function(){
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

Comment: already i follow this way. but i don't want to check authentication in a controllers of each function . if it done at controller of the constructor , it will reduce repeated coding. is it possible at constructor function of a controller .

Comment: Then the simplest way would be to autoload your `user_model` and call the function `$this -> user_model -> logged_in()` without any conditions, and in the function `logged_in()` do the redirection to another function which will simply load the login view.

Comment: @catbadger You will have to change the function name in the controller code. I think that is what you are talking about.